# Windows cannot find rmi registry

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, rmi

I get the following error when doing `start rmiregistry` from command prompt:

> Windows cannot find 'rmiregistry'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

I want to start Java's rmi server from command prompt. I firstly change directory to the following path of the project: `cd C:\Practical1\src\java\practical1` Then to start the server i write `start rmiregistry` I have also set some system variables of java's sdk bin folder.

Maybe i am doing something wrong or i have missed a step and that error comes up?
[image]

Comment: Your PATH doesn't include the JDK or JRE `bin` directory.

Comment: I put that bin path in system variables. In cmd i type the project path

Comment: If you did that correctly, it would have worked. As it doesn't work, you didn't do it correctly. Did you start a new command prompt after updating the system variables?

Comment: Well i did exactly what it shows in the screenshot for cmd part. For system variables i just set the path to java bin folder and i named that java rmi

Comment: I don't know what on earth you mean by 'I named that java rmi', but if you didn't do exactly what I have said here it won't work, and conversely if it doesn't work you haven't done exactly what I said here.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say you what happened, but I can say how to research it.

Try `%JRE_HOME%\bin\rmiregistry.exe`, does it work?

Yes: it's a path problem, no: you have no JRE or `rmiregistry.exe` file.

When «no», make an approptiate installations.

When «yes», type `set path` in command prompt. Do you see full path to JRE's `bin` folder in output?

Yes: it should work, try to type `rmiregistry.exe` just there, does it work?

No: add it to PATH with Windows user interface. Note that you need to restart console (or other application) to use updated environment variables (PATH in our case).

Comment: Find `rmiregistry.exe` file, have you one? What folder? Is path to this folder mentioned in `PATH` environment variable or anywhere?

Comment: yes inside java jdk `C:\JAVA\bin` this is what i have in system  variables

Comment: okay problem solved i had to edit the `path` in system variables and set the bin path